# AdMob show ads in unity on a gameobject

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

I am using AdMob to display ads in my game. However, the position of the ad is 2d, just on the screen. I have a billboard in my game and I really want to show the ads on the billboard inside the screen. How can I do that?

Comment: I very highly doubt that this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

To map a world point to a screen point you can use this: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html. With few calculations you could find the dimension and position of your world object on the scene. However I don't think that the ads can be sized / positioned freely to meet any of your needs. Last I worked with admob the possible placements for ads where predefined ex:  top -right / bottom right etc.